# Realm Sync Progress (iOS / Swift)

Tags: ios, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have setup my app with realm local and sync, all seems to be well. I recently implemented sync progress for multiple remote realms. Which was working great also.

However, after changing some not-sync progress specific code, weird thing happened. For a 50MB database I used to get 5-6 notifications, now I only get the first and when the sync is finished.

I revert back to the old code, same db, it is getting multiple notifications.

I have been trying to solve this for the last couple of days with no luck. Any idea that why this could happen?

In a singleton called `BusinessManager`, I keep references like this:

```
class BusinessManager {
    static let shared = BusinessManager()

    struct SyncNotificationToken {
        let business: Business
        let downloadToken: SyncSession.ProgressNotificationToken
        let uploadToken: SyncSession.ProgressNotificationToken
    }

    private var syncTokens: [String:SyncNotificationToken] = [:]
}
```

Update the sync progress references in each change to the realm:

```
private func configureRemoteBusinessesNotification() {
    guard let remoteBusinesses = remoteBusinesses else { DLog("ERROR obtaining remote businesses"); assert(false); return }

    remoteBusinessesNotificationToken?.stop()

    remoteBusinessesNotificationToken = remoteBusinesses.addNotificationBlock { changes in
        switch changes {
        case .initial:
            self.delegate?.loadedRemoteBusinesses()
            self.updateBusinessProgresses()

        case .update(let results, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
            self.delegate?.remoteNotificationUpdate(results: results, deletions: deletions, insertions: insertions, modifications: modifications)
            self.updateBusinessProgresses()

        case .error(let error):
            self.delegate?.notificationError(error)
        }
    }
}
```

After each change, I discard the old progress and create a new one (I tried holding a reference and skipped creating if the progress exists; that did not make any difference in terms of the problem that I am having).

Each time I receive a progress notification, I create a new struct holding the info and send it via notification (Previously I used a delegate; but since the BusinessManager class is a singleton, I preferred using Notification instead):

```
func updateBusinessProgresses() {
    guard let businesses = remoteBusinesses else { return }
    for business in businesses {
        guard let realmUrl = business.realmSelf.configuration.syncConfiguration?.realmURL else { assert(false); return }
        guard let user = SyncUser.current else { assert(false); return }
        guard let session = user.session(for: realmUrl) else { assert(false); return }

        DLog("PROGRESS URL: \(realmUrl.description)")

        let uploadToken = session.addProgressNotification(for: .upload, mode: .reportIndefinitely, block: { progress in
            DLog("UPLOAD \(progress.transferrableBytes)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let object: [String:Double] = [business.uuid:progress.fractionTransferred]
                DLog("UPLOAD \(business.uuid), fractionTransferred: \(Int(progress.fractionTransferred*100))")
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Upload.name, object: object)
            }
        })

        let downloadToken = session.addProgressNotification(for: .download, mode: .reportIndefinitely, block: { progress in
            DLog("DOWNLOAD \(progress.transferrableBytes)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let object: [String:Double] = [business.uuid:progress.fractionTransferred]
                DLog("DOWNLOAD \(business.uuid), fractionTransferred: \(Int(progress.fractionTransferred*100))")
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Download.name, object: object)
            }
         })

        guard let _uploadToken = uploadToken, let _downloadToken = downloadToken else { assert(false); return }
        // hold a reference so that we keep getting the progresses
        syncTokens[business.uuid] = SyncNotificationToken(business: business, downloadToken: _downloadToken, uploadToken: _uploadToken)
    }
}
```

What could be the reason I am receiving a notification at the start and at the end of the sync progress and no progress update in between?

Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: Katsumi from Realm here. Could you send a reproducible project or sample code to `help@realm.io`?

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi just did. Deleted most of the code of the original project in order to strip it down. Problem still exists. Hope to hear from you. And thanks!